# Filtering "DistinguishedName" Output with Search-ADAccount

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to search through AD using the `Search-ADAccount` cmdlet to find accounts which are Enabled but haven't logged in for the last 90 days. The below commands adequately finds enabled AD accounts on the domains which haven't logged in the last 90 days. However, I'm trying to filtering out any entries where the "DistinguishedName" field includes the text of "Service Account".

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 90.00:00:00 |
    Select-Object -Property Name, Enabled, LastLogonDate, DistinguishedName |
    Where-Object {
        $_.Enabled -like 'True' -and
        $_.DistinguishName -notmatch "Service Account"
    }
```

The above command seems to work fine for finding the enabled accounts and last logon. However, whatever text I put in `-notmatch "..."` seems to be disregarded by PowerShell?
Also tried `-notLike` and I get the same behavior also.

Comment: Unless you really only want the specified properties, drop the `Select-Object` call.  This creates a new object for each one returned from AD and copies over the specified properties - dropping it will be more efficient.  Use `Format-Table`, or similar, to output just the ones you want to see.  If you _do_ want to select like this, then try swapping the `Select-Object` and `Where-Object` calls, as you are potentially duplicating a lot of objects, only to discard them immediately afterwards. The other way will only duplicate objects you are actually interested in.

Comment: Also, note that you have misspelled `DistinguishName ` in your `Where-Object` filter.  Use something like this:  `-and $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*Service Account*"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks boxdog for noticing the mis-spelling of the `DisinguishedName` in the `Where-Object` missing the "ed". This fixed the issue in combination with your other comment about the missing `*Service Account*` wildcards.

Updated PowerShell command:

```
 Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 90.00:00:00 | 
   Where-Object {
      $_.Enabled -like 'True' -and 
      $_.DistinguishedName -NotLike "*Service Account*"
   } | 
   Select-Object -Property Name,Enabled,LastLogonDate,DistinguishedName
```